# Tensorflow recognizes but won't use my GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm using Tensorflow 1.13 from the docker image [tensorflow/tensorflow:1.13.1-gpu-py3-jupyter](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags?page=2) using the Estimator API. I have a machine with 4 K-80 GPUs. When I train the model, the logs indicate that Tensorflow can see my devices. However, when looking at the model graph on Tensorboard, it says that it's only using the CPUs. Looking at global steps/sec in Tensorboard, it says that the model on the machine with the GPUs is taking slightly (but about the same) amount of global steps/sec as it does on my laptop that's using CPUs only.

My training code:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    model_dir=args['model_dir'],
    feature_columns=[tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='val')],
    hidden_units=args['hidden_units'],
    n_classes=args['num_classes'],
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
        learning_rate=args['learning_rate'],
    ))

def gen_input_fn(data, target_column, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_epochs=1):
    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=data,
        y=data[str(target_column)],
        shuffle=shuffle,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_epochs=num_epochs
    )

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=gen_input_fn(train_data, train_data.shape[1], num_epochs=args['num_epochs']))
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=gen_input_fn(eval_data, eval_data.shape[1], shuffle=False), throttle_secs=args['throttle_secs'])

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What nvidia-smi monitor shows? Is there a GPU utilization?

Comment: It does. During training, 1 of my 4 cards gets 1-10% usage, so I guess the _unknown device_ block in Tensorboard is in fact my GPUs.

Comment: unknown device is ok with estimator. try constructing input pipeline with dataset api

Comment: Will do. Thanks. I'm currently using the native `pandas_input_fn` and I'm slightly surprised it doesn't use the dataset stuff.